# Javascript multiply accuracy

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

For some reason when I'm multiplying numbers, when the number gets larger than 10,000,000 I start to see problems with accuracy. Here's the code:

```
this.multiply = function(quantity, value, id) {
    var math = quantity * value;
    document.getElementById(id).value = math.toFixed(2);
}
```

Here's the values that I get:

```
11111     -> 11111.00
111111    -> 111111.00
1111111   -> 1111111.04
11111111  -> 11111110.45
111111111 -> 111111116.41
```

It just gets worse from there.
Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix this accuracy problem?

Comment: What is the code that calls `multiply`? Where are the arguments coming from?

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Some bug in your code before doing toFixed. On chrome it is correct  111111111.00 for 111111111

Comment: zzzzBov was quite right. Don't you know that floating point arithmetic isn't 100% reliable. This isn't issue for js only it's a programming issue.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats: `Each finite number is described by three integers: s = a sign (zero or one), c = a significand (or 'coefficient'), q = an exponent. The numerical value of a finite number is
  (−1)s × c × b^q`

Comment: @Kolink: It's just a dumbed down version of the real name, that's all. The arguments, when checked, are correct.